# Entity Framework with changable database

Tags: entity-framework, multiple-databases

Our clients have tools to change database schema..add columns change column type etc...

There is a way to use EF in that scenario?

I know about code first approach and that if I add column to a table in the `.edmx` schema I can run update data base and the changes will reflect in the data base.

I'm looking for the opposite way if a user change a column in the data base how and where can I run a EF command to update the `.edmx` in a specific project...

And if there is already a better solution for this purpose I will be happy to know.

Thanks a lot!

Israel

Comment: http://bit.ly/1a5TSQe

Comment: Code first doesn't use edmx files. Code first has a tool for importing the objects from an existing database. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj200620.aspx